# Whats the big deal with $nh/(2 \pi)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms, discrete

> $$mvr = nh / (2 \pi)$$

I read this equation, in my textbook and it says that it was a very important thing in Bohr's model and also one of the equations which won him a Nobel.

But I am just not able to appreciate it's beauty! What is so important in this equation and what does it really tells us about the real world?

**Edit-**  People want me to clarify this more. All I am trying to say is what is so special in the idea that the angular momentum is an integral multiple of $h/2$$\pi$ ? What is so revolutionary about this idea?

Comment: Sorry about this bump, but how could de Broglie assume that an integral number of wavelengths fit the circumference of the electron orbit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quantity $mvr$ is the [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) of the electron in the hydrogen atom. $m$ is the electron mass and $v$ is the electron velocity, so $mv$ is the electron momentum, and $r$ is the electron-proton distance.

Bohr's model is that the angular momentum is quantised i.e. it can only take discrete values $\hbar$, $2\hbar$, $3\hbar$, etc. The general rule is that the angular momentum can only have the value $n\hbar$ for some integer $n$. This simple assumption allowed the spectrum of the hydrogen atom to be explained.

It's hard now to appreciate how revolutionary this was at the time. At no point in the two millenia or so that humans had been studying the motion of objects had it been suggested that the constants of motion were anything other than continuous. It was a massive jump to suggest that this did not apply at the atomic scale, but this apparently simple suggestion offered an explanation for a phenomenon (atomic spectra) that was at the time utterly mysterious.

The Bohr model for the atom turned out to be wrong, but the underlying principle that angular momentum is quantised remains true to this day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But can you please explain that how does that assumption explain the spectra of H?

Comment: @AaryanDewan: you can [read about this on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) or on this site you'll find [lots of questions relating to the Bohr model](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=bohr+model).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that this equation requires a physical quantity must be an integer of a unit, just like charge of an item should be an integer number of e. As a consequence, this results in the energy spectrum of the system to be discrete, which gives the structure of Hamiltonian a discrete matrix form rather than continuous one (which, in principle, influences the normalization and commutator relation).